# String to int with help of for-loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have input string written in this form:

```
S = 2222+576666
```

And I need with help for-loop and "+" sign to extract digits before and after "+"

```
for position in range(0,len(S)):
      # Missing part of code I need help with to get desired solution
      number1 = 2222
      number2 = 576666
```

I am not allowed to use any import or any fancy function like split() or raw_input().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
s = "2222+576666"
l = [""] * 2
i = 0
for c in s:
    if c == '+':
        i = 1
        continue
    l[i] += c
num1 = int(l[0])
num2 = int(l[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
counter = 0
for position in range(0,len(S)):
    if S[position] <> '+':
       astr[counter] = S[position]
      counter = counter+1
    else:
      number1 = int(astr)
       astr = ''
       counter = 0
number2 = int(astr2)
```